# syntax checking for params with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I know how much params $msg has but I cant figure out how to count the number of {x} in $cmd_data.
If I had both the counts, I can compare and then see if the user entered enough params for the cmd.

I've tried it with m/{(\d+)}/g and then using **scalar** to get the number of matches.
But this always returned zero.

The code that replaces {x} in $cmd_data with params from $msg.

```
my $syntax_error = 0;
my @params = split(/\s+/, $msg); 
my $msg_param_count = @params;

for(my $i = 1; $i < $msg_param_count; $i++) {
    $cmd_data =~ s/\{$i\}/$params[$i]/g;
}

$server->command(sprintf("msg $target %s.", $cmd_data));
```

**OUTPUT**

```
$msg = "!test param1 param2 param3";
$cmd_data = "test command: {1} {2} {3}";
$output = "test command: param1 param2 param3";
```

Comment: you want me to edit that question? I was told that this is impolite. @aliteralmind

Comment: It is a different question. No need to refer to previously asked questions.

Comment: Yes its different, I already have a way to replace with a regex. I just need help on obtaining param count, to see whether or not the syntax is correct.

Comment: @NullBy7e You have not followed my advice and created an sscce. You are also asking for people to do your programming for you, instead of asking about programming.

Comment: @TPL asking about programming? I post here to ask for help/assistance on my issue. Is that not what stackoverflow is for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of matches inside your string:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cmd_data = "test command: {1} {2} {3}";

print scalar(() = $cmd_data =~ m/{(\d+)}/g);
```

Outputs

```
3
```

If your earlier question is a guide, I suspect this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though.

Comment: thank you this fixed my issue, unlike the others you actually helped me twice, much respect man!